# Deploy new repository image to lambda by aws cli command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have three `lambda` , and each uses the image from `ECR`.

Every time I push the image in `ECR`,

I go to the lambda console then -> deploy new image -> select container image from popup.

It is a bit bothersome procedure for repeating for every `lambda`.

Is there any good way to do this in `aws cli`??

I have checked the aws cli lambda command and guess that `aws lambda update-function-code` is close to my purpose.

However I cant find the precise answer.

How can I deploy the `latest` tagged image in repository to the `lambda` image??

Comment: ```aws lambda update-function-code``` with the additional parameter --image-uri should be the correct one. There you can provide the URI of you ECR image. Without providing a tag, "latest" will be automatically be used.

Comment: Note that the update can take some time. To see if it is complete, call `aws lambda get-function-configuration` on the same function name and review the "LastUpdateStatus" field. When it is ready, it should say "Successful".

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name $MY_FUNC --image-uri $(aws lambda get-function --function-name $MY_FUNC | jq -r '.Code.ImageUri')
```

You must have correct env setup though.

Comment: Note this only works if your lambda is currently using a tag and that tag is refreshed, for example `latest`

Comment: you also need to add `--format json` in the get-function command


`aws lambda update-function-code --function-name $MY_FUNC --image-uri $(aws lambda get-function --output json --function-name $MY_FUNC | jq -r '.Code.ImageUri')`

Comment: Your example will get the current deployed image, not the latest.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to deploy the latest uploaded image you need to tag the image when uploading it.

This example will work only if you use `latest` tag on your images:

```
aws lambda update-function-code --profile plantsnap --function-name $YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME --image-uri $(echo "$ECR_REPO_FUNCTION_PREFIX@$(aws ecr batch-get-image --profile plantsnap --repository-name plantsnap-hybrid-model --image-ids imageTag=latest | jq -e '.images[0].imageId.imageDigest' | tr -d '"')") &> /dev/null
```

Comment: I did --query 'images[0].imageId.imageDigest' --output text instead of jq